# Ext.Net Grid Panel with Selection Model readonly

Tags: extjs

I have a grid panel with a checkbox selection model. I also have an initial set of data to fill the grid: some of the rows that are inserted from code behind ( in the page load ) are checked (example in the image below);

[image]

My problem is that after the initial insertion of the rows I need to make the checkbox uncheckable.

Any suggestions?

I can't use `gridPanel.setReadOnly(true)` and also

```
BeforeDeselect Handler="return false;"
```

(because with that also the initial inserted rows appears unchecked).

Thanks

Comment: Not sure why you would use a selectionModel if you don't want the selection to change at all...

Comment: Because I have two different scenarios: in one the user could check the rows, in the other the user can only see the table but can't modify it (the user is in readonly mode)

Answer (score 0):

You can do following code

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['id', 'name', 'email', 'phone'],
    data: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Lisa',
        email: 'lisa@simpsons.com',
        phone: '555-111-1224'
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Bart',
        email: 'bart@simpsons.com',
        phone: '555-222-1234'
    }, {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Homer',
        email: 'homer@simpsons.com',
        phone: '555-222-1244'
    }, {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Marge',
        email: 'marge@simpsons.com',
        phone: '555-222-1254'
    }]
});

var records = [store.getById(1), store.getById(3)];

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: store,
    columns: [{
        text: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name'
    }, {
        text: 'Email',
        dataIndex: 'email',
        flex: 1
    }, {
        text: 'Phone',
        dataIndex: 'phone'
    }],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    selModel: {
        selType: 'checkboxmodel'
    },
    listeners: {
        boxready: function() {
            this.getSelectionModel().select(records, false, true);
        },
        selectionchange: function() {
            this.getSelectionModel().deselectAll(true);
            this.getSelectionModel().select(records, false, true);
        }
    }
});
```

Records are rows that you want to be selected all the time

Note: It's in ExtJs not Ext.Net

Comment: I can't find a clean solution, so I used a terrible work around: after that the table is populated I  add a style rule to make the panel unclickable